# autocorrelation output in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am currently running an autocorrelation function on a time series information and a plot is being provided. I am finding it hard to interpret it. Is there a way to provide a numerical output rather than a graphical output?

1. This is creating a time series of the data

   ```
   x.ts <- ts(c.tri1.1FG[,10])
   ```
2. Here is the autocorrelation function I am using, based on the above time series

   ```
   acf(x.ts, 100)
   ```
3. This produces the following

   [image]

Any help would be much appreciated in altering the `acf()` to produce numerical output. Or even help in understanding the output of the above graph.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the output to a variable, i.e.

```
## Use acf(x.ts, 100, plot=FALSE)
## To avoid generating a graph
d = acf(x.ts, 100)
```

Then you can look at the components of `d` (a list) via

```
str(d)
```

In particular,

```
d$acf
plot(d$acf)
```

Comment: Thank you. What information is most important to look for in this output in interpreting patterns?

Comment: I would suggest that's a different (statistical) question. Ask another question - perhaps on crossvalidated.